# Python filtering and sorting through a list

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, split

I just can't seem to get this to work. I need to to open file ranger.txt.
Read each line, then split each line into a list of words. Check to see if each word is already in the list. If the word is not in the list, then add it to the list. At end of program, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

The result should be:
["a", "and" "buckle", "C130", "countrollin", "door", "down", "four", "Gonna", "Jump", "little", "out", "ranger", "Recon", "right", "Shuffle", "Standstrip", "the", "to", "take", "trip", "up"]

I can get the individual lists to print, and even one word from each list, but that's it.

```
rangerHandle = open("ranger.txt")
count = 0
rangerList = list()

for line in rangerHandle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #print line works at this point
    words = line.split() # split breaks string makes another list
    #print words works at this point
    if words[count] not in words: 
        rangerList.append(words[count])        
        count += 1
    print rangerList
```

ranger.txt file is:

```
C130 rollin down the strip
Recon ranger
Gonna take a little trip
Stand up, buckle up,
Shuffle to the door
Jump right out and count to four
```

And if you're going to neg vote, please at least give an explanation.

Comment: You specified that words should only be added to the list if they're not already in there, but your desired result has repeated elements.

Comment: Well...I manually did it, so it was a mistake. But thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

We can create the list without finding duplicates. We are going to remove them later by converting the list to a set. Then we sort the set by doing a case insensitive sort:

```
with open("ranger.txt") as f:
    l = [w for line in f for w in line.strip().split()]
print(sorted(set(l), key=lambda s: s.lower()))
```

Result:

```
[
    'a', 'and', 'buckle', 'C130', 'count', 'door', 'down', 'four', 
    'Gonna', 'Jump', 'little', 'out', 'ranger', 'Recon', 'right', 
    'rollin', 'Shuffle', 'Stand', 'strip', 'take', 'the', 'to', 'trip',
    'up,'
]
```

Comment: @JuniorCompressor You might want to convert them to lower case when adding them to the list. otherwise, you can have duplicates between upper and lower cases. I have the same problem with my answer, but it is easier to fix in yours than in mine.

Comment: Yes the OP can do that, but it's not very clear to me if he wants it.

Comment: Converting to lower case was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is better to use the `with ...` syntax when dealing with files (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Second, if I were you, I would use sets (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) instead of lists. They have the advantage that you cannot add the same element twice, so you do not need to check if the word is already in the set or not. For each line, I will create a new set with the words on that line and merge it with the other words using the `union` method.

```
words = set([])
with open("ranger.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         newset = set(line.rstrip().split())
         words = words.union(newset)
words = sorted(words) ## this line transforms the set into a sorted list
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, I'm trying the file but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: From the ranger.txt file?
C130 rollin down the strip,
Recon ranger,
Gonna take a little trip,
Stand up, buckle up,
Shuffle to the door,
Jump right out and count to four,  -- each line ends with a comma, see original post for actual lines.